# can't create a docker image with java. Error msg is "......: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"

Tags: java, docker, devops, docker-image, docker-java

I use Java to build a Docker image. The Dockerfile and code are ready. I can build an image successfully through CLI, such as:

> docker build -t imgetest:1.0 .

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:6.14.2
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

It is a very simple Dockerfile, only for testing.

But I can't build through Java API. My maven dependency and Java code are:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
public boolean createImages(String repository, String dockerfilePath)
{
    try {
        // Loading from a source
        final File imageFile = new File(dockerfilePath);
        try (InputStream imagePayload = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile))) {
            dockerClient.createImageCmd(repository, imagePayload).exec();
            dockerClient.close();
            logger.info("Build image successfully.");
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dockerClient.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

My docker environment is:
[image: Docker env]
My client is:

```
    public static DockerClient getClient()
    {
        DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder().build();

        DockerClient client = DockerClientBuilder
                .getInstance(config)
                .build();
        return client;
    }
```

The error message is:

```
20:46:18.553 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory - 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 500
1 < Api-Version: 1.40
1 < Content-Length: 71
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2020 12:46:18 GMT
1 < Docker-Experimental: false
1 < Ostype: linux
1 < Server: Docker/19.03.8 (linux)
{"message":"Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"}


20:46:18.566 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory$1 - Connection [id: 0][route: {}->unix://localhost:80] can be kept alive indefinitely
20:46:18.566 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
20:46:18.567 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory$1 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->unix://localhost:80][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.filter.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:736)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:735)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:327)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyInvocationBuilder.post(JerseyInvocationBuilder.java:145)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.CreateImageCmdExec.execute(CreateImageCmdExec.java:33)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.CreateImageCmdExec.execute(CreateImageCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:21)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
```

Who can help me giving some ideas? Thanks ahead.

Comment: can you also paste the dockerfile content here?

Comment: Yes. already added.

Comment: I have never used `docker-java`, but seems like it supports multiple transports, have you tried with other transports, say okhttp or netty, do you see same error?

See the note from their official doc:  "Since Apache HttpClient 5-based transport is available now, there is no reason to keep Jersey and it will eventually be removed."  https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/transports.md#jersey

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for this issue. It works for me.

```
BuildImageResultCallback callback = new BuildImageResultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(BuildResponseItem item) {
                        System.out.println("" + item);
                        super.onNext(item);
                        }
                    };
File baseDir = new File(dockerfilePath);
String imageId = dockerClient.buildImageCmd(baseDir).exec(callback).awaitImageId();
```